# Unable to access the Jenkins on localhost/jenkins

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, docker-for-mac

I am new to Kubernetes and ingress.
I am trying to setup Jenkins master and slave using helm on kubernetes on docker on mac.

More info:
I also installed ingress from the following [link](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#detect-installed-version)

Here is my values.yaml

```
clusterZone: "cluster.local"

master:
  # Used for label app.kubernetes.io/component
  componentName: "jenkins-master"
  image: "jenkins/jenkins"
  imageTag: "lts"
  imagePullPolicy: "Always"
  imagePullSecretName:
  # Optionally configure lifetime for master-container
  lifecycle:
  #  postStart:
  #    exec:
  #      command:
  #      - "uname"
  #      - "-a"
  numExecutors: 0
  # configAutoReload requires UseSecurity is set to true:
  useSecurity: true
  # Allows to configure different SecurityRealm using Jenkins XML
  securityRealm: |-
    <securityRealm class="hudson.security.LegacySecurityRealm"/>
  # Allows to configure different AuthorizationStrategy using Jenkins XML
  authorizationStrategy: |-
     <authorizationStrategy class="hudson.security.FullControlOnceLoggedInAuthorizationStrategy">
       <denyAnonymousReadAccess>true</denyAnonymousReadAccess>
     </authorizationStrategy>
  hostNetworking: false
  # When enabling LDAP or another non-Jenkins identity source, the built-in admin account will no longer exist.
  # Since the AdminUser is used by configAutoReload, in order to use configAutoReload you must change the
  # .master.adminUser to a valid username on your LDAP (or other) server.  This user does not need
  # to have administrator rights in Jenkins (the default Overall:Read is sufficient) nor will it be granted any
  # additional rights.  Failure to do this will cause the sidecar container to fail to authenticate via SSH and enter
  # a restart loop.  Likewise if you disable the non-Jenkins identity store and instead use the Jenkins internal one,
  # you should revert master.adminUser to your preferred admin user:
  adminUser: "admin"
  # adminPassword: <defaults to random>
  # adminSshKey: <defaults to auto-generated>
  # If CasC auto-reload is enabled, an SSH (RSA) keypair is needed.  Can either provide your own, or leave unconfigured to allow a random key to be auto-generated.
  # If you supply your own, it is recommended that the values file that contains your key not be committed to source control in an unencrypted format
  rollingUpdate: {}
  # Ignored if Persistence is enabled
  # maxSurge: 1
  # maxUnavailable: 25%
  resources:
    requests:
      cpu: "50m"
      memory: "256Mi"
    limits:
      cpu: "2000m"
      memory: "4096Mi"
  # Environment variables that get added to the init container (useful for e.g. http_proxy)
  # initContainerEnv:
  #   - name: http_proxy
  #     value: "http://192.168.64.1:3128"
  # containerEnv:
  #   - name: http_proxy
  #     value: "http://192.168.64.1:3128"
  # Set min/max heap here if needed with:
  # javaOpts: "-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
  # jenkinsOpts: ""
  # jenkinsUrl: ""
  # If you set this prefix and use ingress controller then you might want to set the ingress path below
  # jenkinsUriPrefix: "/jenkins"
  # Enable pod security context (must be `true` if runAsUser or fsGroup are set)
  usePodSecurityContext: true
  # Set runAsUser to 1000 to let Jenkins run as non-root user 'jenkins' which exists in 'jenkins/jenkins' docker image.
  # When setting runAsUser to a different value than 0 also set fsGroup to the same value:
  # runAsUser: <defaults to 0>
  # fsGroup: <will be omitted in deployment if runAsUser is 0>
  servicePort: 8080
  targetPort: 8080
  # For minikube, set this to NodePort, elsewhere use LoadBalancer
  # Use ClusterIP if your setup includes ingress controller
  serviceType: LoadBalancer
  # Jenkins master service annotations
  serviceAnnotations: {}
  # Jenkins master custom labels
  deploymentLabels: {}
  #   foo: bar
  #   bar: foo
  # Jenkins master service labels
  serviceLabels: {}
  #   service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: https
  # Put labels on Jenkins master pod
  podLabels: {}
  # Used to create Ingress record (should used with ServiceType: ClusterIP)
  # nodePort: <to set explicitly, choose port between 30000-32767
  # Enable Kubernetes Liveness and Readiness Probes
  # ~ 2 minutes to allow Jenkins to restart when upgrading plugins. Set ReadinessTimeout to be shorter than LivenessTimeout.
  healthProbes: true
  healthProbesLivenessTimeout: 5
  healthProbesReadinessTimeout: 5
  healthProbeLivenessPeriodSeconds: 10
  healthProbeReadinessPeriodSeconds: 10
  healthProbeLivenessFailureThreshold: 5
  healthProbeReadinessFailureThreshold: 3
  healthProbeLivenessInitialDelay: 90
  healthProbeReadinessInitialDelay: 60
  slaveListenerPort: 50000
  slaveHostPort:
  disabledAgentProtocols:
    - JNLP-connect
    - JNLP2-connect
  csrf:
    defaultCrumbIssuer:
      enabled: true
      proxyCompatability: true
  cli: false
  # Kubernetes service type for the JNLP slave service
  # slaveListenerServiceType is the Kubernetes Service type for the JNLP slave service,
  # either 'LoadBalancer', 'NodePort', or 'ClusterIP'
  # Note if you set this to 'LoadBalancer', you *must* define annotations to secure it. By default
  # this will be an external load balancer and allowing inbound 0.0.0.0/0, a HUGE
  # security risk:  https://github.com/kubernetes/charts/issues/1341
  slaveListenerServiceType: "ClusterIP"
  slaveListenerServiceAnnotations: {}
  slaveKubernetesNamespace:

  # Example of 'LoadBalancer' type of slave listener with annotations securing it
  # slaveListenerServiceType: LoadBalancer
  # slaveListenerServiceAnnotations:
  #   service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: "True"
  #   service.beta.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-source-ranges: "172.0.0.0/8, 10.0.0.0/8"

  # LoadBalancerSourcesRange is a list of allowed CIDR values, which are combined with ServicePort to
  # set allowed inbound rules on the security group assigned to the master load balancer
  loadBalancerSourceRanges:
  - 0.0.0.0/0
  # Optionally assign a known public LB IP
  # loadBalancerIP: 1.2.3.4
  # Optionally configure a JMX port
  # requires additional javaOpts, ie
  # javaOpts: >
  #   -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=4000
  #   -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
  #   -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
  # jmxPort: 4000
  # Optionally configure other ports to expose in the master container
  extraPorts:
  # - name: BuildInfoProxy
  #   port: 9000

  # List of plugins to be install during Jenkins master start
  installPlugins:
    - kubernetes:1.16.0
    - workflow-job:2.32
    - workflow-aggregator:2.6
    - credentials-binding:1.19
    - git:3.10.0

  # Enable to always override the installed plugins with the values of 'master.installPlugins' on upgrade or redeployment.
  # overwritePlugins: true
  # Enable HTML parsing using OWASP Markup Formatter Plugin (antisamy-markup-formatter), useful with ghprb plugin.
  # The plugin is not installed by default, please update master.installPlugins.
  enableRawHtmlMarkupFormatter: false
  # Used to approve a list of groovy functions in pipelines used the script-security plugin. Can be viewed under /scriptApproval
  scriptApproval:
  #  - "method groovy.json.JsonSlurperClassic parseText java.lang.String"
  #  - "new groovy.json.JsonSlurperClassic"
  # List of groovy init scripts to be executed during Jenkins master start
  initScripts:
  #  - |
  #    print 'adding global pipeline libraries, register properties, bootstrap jobs...'
  # Kubernetes secret that contains a 'credentials.xml' for Jenkins
  # credentialsXmlSecret: jenkins-credentials
  # Kubernetes secret that contains files to be put in the Jenkins 'secrets' directory,
  # useful to manage encryption keys used for credentials.xml for instance (such as
  # master.key and hudson.util.Secret)
  # secretsFilesSecret: jenkins-secrets
  # Jenkins XML job configs to provision
  jobs:
  #  test: |-
  #    <<xml here>>

  # Below is the implementation of Jenkins Configuration as Code.  Add a key under configScripts for each configuration area,
  # where each corresponds to a plugin or section of the UI.  Each key (prior to | character) is just a label, and can be any value.
  # Keys are only used to give the section a meaningful name.  The only restriction is they may only contain RFC 1123 \ DNS label
  # characters: lowercase letters, numbers, and hyphens.  The keys become the name of a configuration yaml file on the master in
  # /var/jenkins_home/casc_configs (by default) and will be processed by the Configuration as Code Plugin.  The lines after each |
  # become the content of the configuration yaml file.  The first line after this is a JCasC root element, eg jenkins, credentials,
  # etc.  Best reference is https://<jenkins_url>/configuration-as-code/reference.  The example below creates a welcome message:
  JCasC:
    enabled: false
    pluginVersion: "1.21"
    # it's only used when plugin version is <=1.18 for later version the
    # configuration as code support plugin is no longer needed
    supportPluginVersion: "1.18"
    configScripts:
      welcome-message: |
        jenkins:
          systemMessage: Welcome to our CI\CD server.  This Jenkins is configured and managed 'as code'.

  # Optionally specify additional init-containers
  customInitContainers: []
  # - name: custom-init
  #   image: "alpine:3.7"
  #   imagePullPolicy: Always
  #   command: [ "uname", "-a" ]

  sidecars:
    configAutoReload:
      # If enabled: true, Jenkins Configuration as Code will be reloaded on-the-fly without a reboot.  If false or not-specified,
      # jcasc changes will cause a reboot and will only be applied at the subsequent start-up.  Auto-reload uses the Jenkins CLI
      # over SSH to reapply config when changes to the configScripts are detected.  The admin user (or account you specify in
      # master.adminUser) will have a random SSH private key (RSA 4096) assigned unless you specify adminSshKey.  This will be saved to a k8s secret.
      enabled: false
      image: shadwell/k8s-sidecar:0.0.2
      imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
      resources:
        #   limits:
        #     cpu: 100m
        #     memory: 100Mi
        #   requests:
        #     cpu: 50m
        #     memory: 50Mi
      # SSH port value can be set to any unused TCP port.  The default, 1044, is a non-standard SSH port that has been chosen at random.
      # Is only used to reload jcasc config from the sidecar container running in the Jenkins master pod.
      # This TCP port will not be open in the pod (unless you specifically configure this), so Jenkins will not be
      # accessible via SSH from outside of the pod.  Note if you use non-root pod privileges (runAsUser & fsGroup),
      # this must be > 1024:
      sshTcpPort: 1044
      # folder in the pod that should hold the collected dashboards:
      folder: "/var/jenkins_home/casc_configs"
      # If specified, the sidecar will search for JCasC config-maps inside this namespace.
      # Otherwise the namespace in which the sidecar is running will be used.
      # It's also possible to specify ALL to search in all namespaces:
      # searchNamespace:

    # Allows you to inject additional/other sidecars
    other:
    ## The example below runs the client for https://smee.io as sidecar container next to Jenkins,
    ## that allows to trigger build behind a secure firewall.
    ## https://jenkins.io/blog/2019/01/07/webhook-firewalls/#triggering-builds-with-webhooks-behind-a-secure-firewall
    ##
    ## Note: To use it you should go to https://smee.io/new and update the url to the generete one.
    # - name: smee
    #   image: docker.io/twalter/smee-client:1.0.2
    #   args: ["--port", "{{ .Values.master.servicePort }}", "--path", "/github-webhook/", "--url", "https://smee.io/new"]
    #   resources:
    #     limits:
    #       cpu: 50m
    #       memory: 128Mi
    #     requests:
    #       cpu: 10m
    #       memory: 32Mi
  # Node labels and tolerations for pod assignment
  # ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#nodeselector
  # ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#taints-and-tolerations-beta-feature
  nodeSelector: {}
  tolerations: []
  # Leverage a priorityClass to ensure your pods survive resource shortages
  # ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/pod-priority-preemption/
  # priorityClass: system-cluster-critical
  podAnnotations: {}

  # The below two configuration-related values are deprecated and replaced by Jenkins Configuration as Code (see above
  # JCasC key).  They will be deleted in an upcoming version.
  customConfigMap: false
  # By default, the configMap is only used to set the initial config the first time
  # that the chart is installed.  Setting `overwriteConfig` to `true` will overwrite
  # the jenkins config with the contents of the configMap every time the pod starts.
  # This will also overwrite all init scripts
  overwriteConfig: false

  # By default, the Jobs Map is only used to set the initial jobs the first time
  # that the chart is installed.  Setting `overwriteJobs` to `true` will overwrite
  # the jenkins jobs configuration with the contents of Jobs every time the pod starts.
  overwriteJobs: false

  ingress:
    enabled: true
    # For Kubernetes v1.14+, use 'networking.k8s.io/v1beta1'
    apiVersion: "extensions/v1beta1"
    labels: {}
    annotations: {}
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
    # Set this path to jenkinsUriPrefix above or use annotations to rewrite path
    path: "/jenkins"
    # configures the hostname e.g. jenkins.example.com
    hostName: localhost
    # tls:
    # - secretName: jenkins.cluster.local
    #   hosts:
    #     - jenkins.cluster.local

  # Openshift route
  route:
    enabled: false
    labels: {}
    annotations: {}
    # path: "/jenkins"

  additionalConfig: {}

  # master.hostAliases allows for adding entries to Pod /etc/hosts:
  # https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/add-entries-to-pod-etc-hosts-with-host-aliases/
  hostAliases: []
  # - ip: 192.168.50.50
  #   hostnames:
  #     - something.local
  # - ip: 10.0.50.50
  #   hostnames:
  #     - other.local

  # Expose Prometheus metrics
  prometheus:
    # If enabled, add the prometheus plugin to the list of plugins to install
    # https://plugins.jenkins.io/prometheus
    enabled: false
    # Additional labels to add to the ServiceMonitor object
    serviceMonitorAdditionalLabels: {}
    scrapeInterval: 60s
    # This is the default endpoint used by the prometheus plugin
    scrapeEndpoint: /prometheus
    # Additional labels to add to the PrometheusRule object
    alertingRulesAdditionalLabels: {}
    # An array of prometheus alerting rules
    # See here: https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/alerting_rules/
    # The `groups` root object is added by default, simply add the rule entries
    alertingrules: []

agent:
  enabled: true
  image: "jenkins/jnlp-slave"
  imageTag: "3.27-1"
  customJenkinsLabels: []
  # name of the secret to be used for image pulling
  imagePullSecretName:
  componentName: "jenkins-slave"
  privileged: false
  resources:
    requests:
      cpu: "200m"
      memory: "256Mi"
    limits:
      cpu: "200m"
      memory: "256Mi"
  # You may want to change this to true while testing a new image
  alwaysPullImage: false
  # Controls how slave pods are retained after the Jenkins build completes
  # Possible values: Always, Never, OnFailure
  podRetention: "Never"
  # You can define the volumes that you want to mount for this container
  # Allowed types are: ConfigMap, EmptyDir, HostPath, Nfs, Pod, Secret
  # Configure the attributes as they appear in the corresponding Java class for that type
  # https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-plugin/tree/master/src/main/java/org/csanchez/jenkins/plugins/kubernetes/volumes
  # Pod-wide ennvironment, these vars are visible to any container in the slave pod
  envVars:
  # - name: PATH
  #   value: /usr/local/bin
  volumes:
  # - type: Secret
  #   secretName: mysecret
  #   mountPath: /var/myapp/mysecret
  # - type: EmptyDir
  #   mountPath: "/var/lib/containers"
  #   memory: false
  nodeSelector: {}
  # Key Value selectors. Ex:
  # jenkins-agent: v1

  # Executed command when side container gets started
  command:
  args:
  # Side container name
  sideContainerName: "jnlp"
  # Doesn't allocate pseudo TTY by default
  TTYEnabled: false
  # Max number of spawned agent
  containerCap: 10
  # Pod name
  podName: "default"
  # Allows the Pod to remain active for reuse until the configured number of
  # minutes has passed since the last step was executed on it.
  idleMinutes: 0
  # Raw yaml template for the Pod. For example this allows usage of toleration for agent pods.
  # https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-plugin#using-yaml-to-define-pod-templates
  # https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/taint-and-toleration/
  yamlTemplate:
  # yamlTemplate: |-
  #   apiVersion: v1
  #   kind: Pod
  #   spec:
  #     tolerations:
  #     - key: "key"
  #       operator: "Equal"
  #       value: "value"

persistence:
  enabled: true
  ## A manually managed Persistent Volume and Claim
  ## Requires persistence.enabled: true
  ## If defined, PVC must be created manually before volume will be bound
  existingClaim:
  ## jenkins data Persistent Volume Storage Class
  ## If defined, storageClassName: <storageClass>
  ## If set to "-", storageClassName: "", which disables dynamic provisioning
  ## If undefined (the default) or set to null, no storageClassName spec is
  ##   set, choosing the default provisioner.  (gp2 on AWS, standard on
  ##   GKE, AWS & OpenStack)
  ##
  storageClass:
  annotations: {}
  accessMode: "ReadWriteOnce"
  size: "8Gi"
  volumes:
  #  - name: nothing
  #    emptyDir: {}
  mounts:
  #  - mountPath: /var/nothing
  #    name: nothing
  #    readOnly: true

networkPolicy:
  # Enable creation of NetworkPolicy resources.
  enabled: false
  # For Kubernetes v1.4, v1.5 and v1.6, use 'extensions/v1beta1'
  # For Kubernetes v1.7, use 'networking.k8s.io/v1'
  apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1

## Install Default RBAC roles and bindings
rbac:
  create: true

serviceAccount:
  create: true
  # The name of the service account is autogenerated by default
  name:
  annotations: {}

serviceAccountAgent:
  # Specifies whether a ServiceAccount should be created
  create: false
  # The name of the ServiceAccount to use.
  # If not set and create is true, a name is generated using the fullname template
  name:
  annotations: {}

## Backup cronjob configuration
## Ref: https://github.com/nuvo/kube-tasks
backup:
  # Backup must use RBAC
  # So by enabling backup you are enabling RBAC specific for backup
  enabled: false
  # Used for label app.kubernetes.io/component
  componentName: "backup"
  # Schedule to run jobs. Must be in cron time format
  # Ref: https://crontab.guru/
  schedule: "0 2 * * *"
  annotations:
    # Example for authorization to AWS S3 using kube2iam
    # Can also be done using environment variables
    iam.amazonaws.com/role: "jenkins"
  image:
    repository: "nuvo/kube-tasks"
    tag: "0.1.2"
  # Additional arguments for kube-tasks
  # Ref: https://github.com/nuvo/kube-tasks#simple-backup
  extraArgs: []
  # Add existingSecret for AWS credentials
  existingSecret: {}
  ## Example for using an existing secret
   # jenkinsaws:
  ## Use this key for AWS access key ID
     # awsaccesskey: jenkins_aws_access_key
  ## Use this key for AWS secret access key
     # awssecretkey: jenkins_aws_secret_key
  # Add additional environment variables
  env:
  # Example environment variable required for AWS credentials chain
  - name: "AWS_REGION"
    value: "us-east-1"
  resources:
    requests:
      memory: 1Gi
      cpu: 1
    limits:
      memory: 1Gi
      cpu: 1
  destination: "s3://nuvo-jenkins-data/backup"
checkDeprecation: true
```

But I am not able to access the Jenkins on localhost/jenkins. I also tried jenkins.clutser.local.

Can someone please let me know how it works. ?

[image]

Ingress :

```
#kubectl describe ing jenkins 
Name:             jenkins
Namespace:        jenkins
Address:
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (<none>)
Rules:
  Host  Path  Backends
  ----  ----  --------
  *
        /   jenkins:8080 (<none>)
Annotations:

    Events:  <none>
```

I tried this [example](https://matthewpalmer.net/kubernetes-app-developer/articles/kubernetes-ingress-guide-nginx-example.html) app also this is also not working for me.

For this example:

```
curl -kL http://localhost/banana
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused
```

Comment: You have failed to specify what "not able to access" means: connection refused? connection timeout? 404? 500? You have failed to include any `kubectl` output. You have failed to include one shred of log output. The Internet is not psychic -- if you want help, you have to share details and any existing troubleshooting you have done, if any

Comment: Hey Matthew, Thanks for commenting. I have updated my question. I have this info only.

Comment: Please include `kubectl get --all-namespaces pods -o wide` so we can see if the pods are in fact running and ready. In the future, it would be tremendously helpful to use the `-v` argument to curl, since that would include helpful debugging information